# How do I make time independent of the FPS?

Tags: java, physics, frame-rate

I have a program which runs the `tick()` method every frame. I want an object to fall according to a set gravity constant, so I created a `Ball` object which will update its position to the position on the previous frame minus the y velocity. The y velocity will decrease by the gravity constant each tick. But the fall is far too rapid because the ticks do not directly translate to seconds. I think I'm missing some basic math but I'm juggling so many variables I can't see what it is.

**EDIT:** Added code

```
@Override
public void run(){
    init();

    long lastTime=System.nanoTime(), timer=System.currentTimeMillis();
    final double ticks=60.0;
    double ns=1000000000/ticks, delta=0;
    int updates=0, frames=0;

    while(running){
        long now=System.nanoTime();
        delta+=(now-lastTime)/ns;
        lastTime=now;

        if(delta>=1){
            tick();
            updates++;
            delta--;
        }

        render();
        frames++;

        if((System.currentTimeMillis()-timer)>1000){
             timer+=1000;
             System.out.println(updates+" ticks, FPS "+frames);
             frame.setTitle("Ball -- "+SCALEWIDTH+"x"+SCALEHEIGHT+" at "+frames+" FPS");
             updates=0;
             frames=0;
        }
    }
    stop();
}
```

Comment: Your `tick()` function could return a time delta (the amount of time passed since the last tick). Then you can use that in your calculation of the new y-velocity.

Comment: I think I need to reanalyze the program. It was modified from a tutorial. In general terms, what should I be looking for? Divide the framerate by the time between ticks to get "real-time"?

Comment: For Java, you don't divide anything.  You just call `System.nanotime()` and use the difference to determine how much time has passed since the last call.  That difference is your time step.

Answer (score 3):

For each update frame, you will need to compute the time in seconds between now and the previous update. This will need to be a float or double since it will likely be a fraction of a second. To do this, you get the current time in milliseconds or nanoseconds, subtract the previous time, and convert to seconds.

You can then use a process called **numerical integration** to compute the new position and velocity. This means finding an approximation to the equations of motion by computing the position and velocity in the current frame based on computations from the previous frame and the time between them. This looks something like:

```
position += velocity * dt;
velocity += acceleration * dt;
```

where `dt` is the time between frames in seconds. This particular method for integrating position and velocity is called the **Euler Method**.  This method is easy and it might work just fine for your application, but it starts to become inaccurate over time when velocity or acceleration is not constant. This is because the values being calculated are an approximation to a curve.

If you need more accuracy, you will want to look into other integration methods like **Verlet** or **Runge-Kutta**.

Comment: Is the delta in my code not time between seconds? I thought it was, but when I tested it the object moved way too fast.

Comment: I changed the code so it's `velocity -= g/2*(dt^2);` to match the actual equation for projectile motion and it looks right, but I'm fairly sure that mathematically it is not right.

Comment: It looks like there's a couple problems. dt is the difference between frames, not an accumulation between frames. Each update, compute it as delta = (now - lastTime)/1000000000.0. Then pass this value to wherever you are updating your ball (tick()?) and use it as I've shown above. You shouldn't be adding to or subtracting from delta like in your code, nor dividing by 60.